# Change checkbox value for checked and unchecked in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox and I'd like to change the value if the checkbox is checked or not.

For the moment, my checkbox model value is equal to 'true' if checked and 'false' if unchecked.

My checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="toStringObj" />
```

What I tried

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="anyModel" ng-false-value="''" ng-model="toStringObj" />
```

I works if I put a string in ng-true-value directive, but not with a model, I need to pass a model  from my scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue` only accept constant expressions so it's not possible for them to be set dynamically from a value on your controllers scope.

> Some attributes used in conjunction with ngModel (such as ngTrueValue or ngFalseValue) will only accept constant expressions.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/constexpr